# Convert first letter of every word to uppercase in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to convert the first letter of each word into upper case, as example: "hello world" should be "Hello World".

This is my code so far.

```
function test() {
var doc = document.getElementById("testInput").value;
var str = doc.replace(/\w\S*/g, doc.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + doc.substring(1).toLowerCase());

document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML = str;
}
```

And let's say my input is "hello world", the expected outcome is "Hello World"
but what I get is "Hello world Hello world".

So my problem is that it only assign the first word and skip the second, but it prints the sentence twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially duplicating the values with your concatenations.

By doing the following you will only be passing in the sub-string's that match the regex pattern to then be replaced:

```
function test() {
    var doc = document.getElementById("testInput").value;
    var str = doc.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){ return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });

    document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: That works just like I want! But could you explain some more on why it does? How come the "function(txt)" know it should take doc as the parameter?

Comment: `.abc` becomes `.Abc` and `+abc` becomes `+Abc` is that valid?

Comment: So pretty much what's happening here is you are only passing the substrings one at a time. First, you are passing in "hello" by itself which is assigned to the txt variable. It is then returned as "Hello". Then, you are passing in "world" by itself which is assigned to the txt variable. It is then returned as "World". This provides the end result of "Hello World".

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes that is valid as the '.' or the '+' would not be passed in to the function. The function is only taking in the regex matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
str.split(" ").map(e => e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)).join(" ")
```

Comment: Your code will capitalize **every** letter, not just the first one.

Comment: I just posted my answer and had the realisation, it. It is normal to use the edit feature within seconds of posting the answer.

Comment: This is why SO founders implemented code snippets. Fix it and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @Kinduser I have added the fix.

Comment: Now it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String.prototype.toUpperCaseWords = function () {
    return this.replace(/\w+/g, function(a){ 
      return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    })
  }
```

Usage:

```
var stringVariable = "First put into a var";
stringVariable.toUpperCaseWords(); // Output: First Put Into A Var
```

Source: https://blog.smalldo.gs/2014/06/easily-add-phps-ucwords-ucfirst-to-javascript/

Comment: Do not pollute the `String.prototype`. Just use a simple named function.

Comment: What do you mean with polluting the String.prototype? For someone who doesn't know what that does, why is that worse than a "simple named function"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
function Capitalize(str){
    var arr = str.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++)
    {
    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
    }
    var result = arr.join(" ");
    console.log(result);
    }
    
    Capitalize("hello world");
```

And do you know you can do this only by CSS?

```css
div:hover{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hover on me!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`,`charAt(0).toUpperCase()` for first letter and  `substr(1).toLowerCase()` for the rest of the word. Do this on `input` or `change` event. If you want to do it like the way you got it don't use `innerHTML`, use `textContent` instead.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var inp1 = document.getElementById('input1');


inp1.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  var text = this.value;
  var res = titleCase(text);
  inp2.value = res;
}, false);


function titleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<input id='input1'>
<input id='input2'>
```

Comment: Why textContent instead of innerHTML?

Comment: Sorry didn't explain, it's just faster.

Comment: I agree, textContent would be a better option. No only because it provides some better performance, but it additionally provides some protection against Cross Site Scripting.

Comment: Indeed, I avoid using it so much, it's like a reflex now. If I wanted to write out dynamic elements, I'll use `createElement()`. If I'm not worried about XSS, then I'll use `insertAdjacentHTML()` as it is `innerHTML` on steroids.

Answer (score 0):

```
function capitaizeFirstLetterOfEachWord(str) {
    str = str.split(' ')
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1)
    }
        return str.join(' ')
}
console.log(capitaizeFirstLetterOfEachWord("hello hii how are you"))
```